# SQL - SUM with SUBSTRING

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm trying to SUM some values from a string but I can't seem to make it work.

```
SELECT 
    P.NOME
    ,ISNULL(SUM(VPL.QTD),0) as TQTD
    ,CAST(LEFT(SUBSTRING(P.NOME, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', P.NOME), LEN(P.NOME)),2) AS INT)  
    ,SUM(CAST(LEFT(SUBSTRING(P.NOME, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', P.NOME), LEN(P.NOME)),2) AS INT)) * ISNULL(SUM(VPL.QTD),0)
FROM Tabela1 as P
GROUP BY P.NOME
```

If I comment the SUM I get this:

[image]

But when I try to sum the CAST and the VPL.QTD I get this:

```
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Ga' to data type int."
```

Also, this substring `SUBSTRING(P.NOME, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', P.NOME), LEN(P.NOME)` returns `13 kgs`

I'm using Microsoft Sql Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, you have values where the integer is not followed by another integer.  One possibility is changing the pattern:

```
SUM(CONVERT(INT,
            LEFT(SUBSTRING(P.NOME, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]%', P.NOME), LEN(P.NOME)), 2) 
               )
   ) * ISNULL(SUM(VPL.QTD),0)
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, another is to use `try_convert()`:

```
SUM(TRY_CONVERT(INT,
                LEFT(SUBSTRING(P.NOME, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', P.NOME), LEN(P.NOME)), 2) 
               )
   ) * ISNULL(SUM(VPL.QTD),0)
```

You could also try a `CASE` statement, although I think changing the pattern is the better solution if all names always have two adjacent digits:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN P.NOME LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]%'
         THEN CONVERT(INT,
                      LEFT(SUBSTRING(P.NOME, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]%', P.NOME), LEN(P.NOME)), 2) 
                     )
    END
   ) * ISNULL(SUM(VPL.QTD),0)
```

Comment: The first one returns the same message as the CAST. The second one doesn't work because I'm using a older version. The third one is missing an END before the )* but then I get this message: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2,' to data type int."

Comment: @Enato . . . The first should work.  You are converting two digits to an integer and the first should find the first occurrence of two digits.

Comment: the first option looks good, except it will fail if no 2 digit number is in the string, with the Conversion failed... message.

Comment: @KM. . . . Hence the third option.  The `case` guarantees the order of evaluation (at least when there are no aggregation functions), so that should not be a problem.